# Get id of next object in Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a function that is passed in the `id` of an object in my class `Image`. I need the `id` of the next object in the model. Currently, I am doing it in the least efficient way possible as I need to get all the objects to do this. My current implementation is:

```
def get_next_id(curr_id):  
  result = []
  Image_list = Image.objects.all()
  total = Image.objects.all().count()
  for i in range(len(Image_list)):
    result.append(Image_list[i].id)
  index_curr = result.index(curr_id)
  if index_curr == total:
    new_index = 0
  else:
    new_index = index_curr + 1
  return Image_list[new_index]
```

I would be grateful if someone could provide a better way, or make this one more efficient. Thank you.

Comment: Something like this? `def get_next_id(curr_id):
  try:
    next_image = Image.objects.get(pk=curr_id + 1)
    return next_image
  except DoesNotExist:
    return Image.objects.get(pk=0)` ps. I havent tested it.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/241526). Explain the problem which causes you to want the next id of an image.

Comment: @limelights I can't do that because I delete ids so the next id may not always be the old id + 1.

Comment: @Louis I have made an image gallery and when I press next, I call a function that takes in the id of the current image and uses the `get_next_id` function to display the image which is next in the databse.

Comment: If you have an image gallery and want to browse through the images, then using JavaScript on the client side would be more appropriate way of doing it. Just assign the whole queryset to the template and iterate over it. A JavaScript would than come in and display the next image on click.

Comment: An alternative to my above posted suggestion would be to get all images, paginate them with one image per page and add links to the previous and next image. There is no need of looking for the next id. You have really an XY problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
def get_next_id(curr_id):
    try:
        ret = Image.objects.filter(id__gt=curr_id).order_by("id")[0:1].get().id
    except Image.DoesNotExist:
        ret = Image.objects.aggregate(Min("id"))['id__min']
    return ret
```

This does not take care of the special case where the table is empty, but then you should not have a valid `curr_id` in the first place if the table is empty. It also does not protect against passing nonsensical values as `curr_id`.

What this does is get first id which is greater than the current one. The `[0:1]` slice limits the data returned from the database to the first record: in effect the database is performing the slice rather than Python. If there is no id greater than the current one, then get the lowest one.

In response to your comment about how to do it in reverse:

```
def get_prev_id(curr_id):
    try:
        ret = Image.objects.filter(id__lt=curr_id).order_by("-id")[0:1].get().id
    except Image.DoesNotExist:
        ret = Image.objects.aggregate(Max("id"))['id__max']
    return ret
```

The changes are:

1. Use `id__lt`, and order by `-id`.
2. Use `Max` rather than `Min` for the aggregate, and use the `id__max` key rather than `id__min` to get the value.

Comment: Thanks. This works great. Can you just provide a small explanation about how I can mirror this function with the same efficiency to find the previous id if there is one and the last id if we were passed in the first id. Thank you.

Comment: It's a bit complicated to do it in a comment so I've updated my answer.